# php mysql update statment generation from form values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

I am creating a very small database abstract layer, i want to send an array of variables that i obtained from a form, and generate an update sql statement, and eventually execute it.  *What do I put on the second to last line below?*
for example.

```
$table name = "user";
$username = $_post['username'];
$password = $_post['password'];
$email    = $_post['email'];
$array = (username=>$username, password=>$password, email=>$email);
$query = "update $this->tableName".
$query = """" The value from the assc array in the form of database value='form value' 
$query = "WHERE condition";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `foreach()` loop to generate your query clause from your array.  Note that you need to declare your array with the `array()` construct, and quote your associative keys.

```
//...
$array = array('username'=>$username, 'password'=>$password, 'email'=>$email);
$query = "update ".$this->tableName." SET ";
foreach($array as $field => $value) {
    $query .= "`".$field."`='".mysql_real_escape_string($value)."',";
}
//knock off trailing comma
$query = substr($query,0,-1);
$query .= " WHERE condition";
```

Comment: I am thinking of sending it as a multidimensional array for example
    $multi = array();
    $multi[] = array($customer_id, $domain_name, $purchase_date,
    $expiry_date, $vendor);
    $multi[] = array("c_id", "domain_id", "purchase_date", 
    "expiry_date", "vendor");
how can you implement the foreach on this kind of array?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
$a = array();
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    $a[] = $key . " = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) ."'";
}
$query = join(',', $a);
```

but you need to take care of special cases, for example when the value is null or a date